# Xcode 11 Beta 3 animation no longer works

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have just changed from Xcode 11 Beta 2, to Beta 3, and although I had to also change the navigationButton to navigationLink, all is ok, expect for the .animation()

Has anyone else seen this issue? Have they changed something? I was working just fine in Beta 2.

Thanks !!

```
import SwiftUI

struct BackGround : View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack{
      Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.gray)
        .opacity(0.9)
        .cornerRadius(15.0)
        .shadow(radius: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/10/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        .blur(radius: 5)
        .padding(20)
        .animation(.basic())
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: How does it fail? Compile time? Run time? BTW I've had issues even getting my code to run on my iPhone with Xcode Beta 3 -- changes since Beta 2 will compile but then when run say it can't find the symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. It compiles, and runs in the simulator, but there is no longer any animation happening.. Worked great on beta 2

Comment: I have the same issue but only for Xcode Previews, the animation works if installed to a simulator, greatly increases the iteration loop for developing animations

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I wrapped the content of a view in a VStack, perhaps other Stacks would also work, the view will animate in the previewer

Heres a quick example of a view that if wrapped in a VStack in the PreviewProvider previews the button will animate. But if the VStack is removed it will no longer animate. Try it out!

```
struct AnimatedButton : View {

  @State var isAnimating: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.isAnimating.toggle()
    }) {
      Text("asdf")
    }.foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
      .padding()
      .background(Color(.Green))
      .cornerRadius(20)
      .animation(.spring())
      .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 2.0 : 1.0)
  }
}

#if DEBUG
struct FunButton_Previews : PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    VStack {
      AnimatedButton()
    }
  }
}
#endif
```